# Lose JSON data when changing JQuery from append() to html(), why and how do I stop this (Songkick API)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I took this code from [Sharks with Lazers](http://sharkswithlazers.net/songkick-api-using-jquery-search-and-get-artist-calendar/), modifying it slightly:

```
$(function(){
  var key="My key";
  var url="http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/search/artists.json?query=" + userSearch + "&apikey=" + key + "&jsoncallback=?"; 
  $.getJSON(url,function(json){ 
    $.each(json.resultsPage.results.artist,function(i,result){
      if(i==0){
        artist_url="http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/" + result.id + "/calendar.json?apikey=" + key +"&jsoncallback=?";
        $.getJSON(artist_url,function(data){ 
          $.each(data.resultsPage.results.event,function(i,event){
            for (prop in event) {
              if (!result.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                continue; 
              }
              $("#Gigs").html("<li>" + event[prop]);
            }
          })
        })           
      };
    }); 
  });
});
```

The if (result.displayName=="an_artist_name") wasn't working for me, so if(i==0) seems to work as a workaround. In the original, the code I'm having trouble with is:

```
$("#songkick").append("<li>" + prop + ". " + event[prop]);
```

I've modified it to:

```
$("#Gigs").html("<li>" + event[prop]);
```

Gigs being the id of the element where I want the data to appear. I don't want append() because I want the previous results to be cleared with each subsequent search, but when I change the code from append() to html(), I only get the last "prop", why is that?

With append(), I get Gig Name, Songkick URI, and Songkick ID, but when I change to html() it only gives me the last one, Songkick ID.

Answer (score 1):

Because you clear the html everytime you use `html()` as you already said yourself.

just use append, but clear the html one time at the beginning using:
`if (i == 0) { $("#Gigs").html(""); ...`
and the rest of the time use 
`$("#Gigs").append("<li>" + event[prop]);`
but let me point out also that you should close the `<li>`-tag

Comment: Just read this, it works! Thanks a lot man, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Just noticed one small problem, though, misses first of concert results each time. Don't really get why since adding `if(i == 0)`...

Comment: could you edit your code above the way you changed it to enable me to understand what´s exactly the problem now and what causes it...

Comment: Code is currently:
`$.getJSON(artist_url,function(data){ 
                        $.each(data.resultsPage.results.event,function(i,event){
                        for (prop in event) {
                        if (!result.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        continue; }
                        if (i==0){
                            $("#Gigs").html("");    
                        } else {
                            $("#Gigs").append("<li>" + event[prop]);
                        }
                        }
                        })
                        }) `

Comment: change the if-code to `if (i==0){ $("#Gigs").html(""); } $("#Gigs").append("<li>" + event[prop]);` . the you clear the code in the beginning and in every case you append your elements.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I ended up forgetting a loop and just breaking DRY by repeating the code :P Messy, but it worked.

Comment: seriously, that is really dirty, but still you could add the code you ended up with, maybe i can modify it - im fixed^^